# How do I reference the index number of an HTML collection in my innerHTML button label?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm very new to Javascript, so please forgive me if my thinking is completely off target.

I've got to create three buttons, which I have successfully, if not clumsily done. Ideally, I would like to label these buttons with the index number they reference.

function hideQuestions(){

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    let label = document.getElementsByClassName("question-label");
    console.log(label);
    let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    btn.innerHTML = `Hide Question ${label.item[i]}`
    ol.appendChild(btn);
}
```

}

however, the output looks like
[code & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUdNR.png)

is this possible? Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are going for here, but if you just want the button to show the current index in the label, you could do something like:

```js
btn.innerHTML = `Hide Question ${i+1}`; // I added +1 because it's zero-indexed
```

Since your question is about the HTMLCollection, however, I'm guessing you want to access each label so the button can hide it. An HTMLCollection is not a regular array, but you can use `Array.from` to convert it to one. Another issue with your code is that your are using `document.getElementsByClassName` *INSIDE* the loop, so you get all of the labels each time, instead of just one at a time. The code below will set up each button to hide the correct label:

```js
function hideQuestions(){
    let labels = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("question-label"));
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        btn.innerHTML = `Hide Question ${i+1}`
        let currentLabel = labels[i];
        btn.onclick = function() {
            currentLabel.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        ol.appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

HTMLCollection documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 1):

If you want only index button from 1 to 3 then you could simply do this

```
btn.innerHTML = `Hide Question ${i+1}`
```

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let label = document.getElementsByClassName("question-label");
    console.log(label);
    let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    btn.innerHTML = `Hide Question ${i+1}`
    ol.appendChild(btn);
}
```